# ReactJS: Render Child Component Only

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

New to ReactJS. Using the [mxstbr/react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate).

## Problem:

I have a container (React.Component) that receives data from an async call performed in a redux-saga. When the data is stored into the state, the container updates, as expected with ReactJS. The data is passed to two different child components that use the data to render a chart. The issue is that when data changes that one component uses, the entire view refreshes, which means the other component rerenders.

## Code: container

```
export class Social extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SocialChart data={this.props.socialData} />
        <WeekChart data={this.props.weekData} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

## Code: SocialChart (barebones)

```
class SocialChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Social Chart</p>
    );
  }
}
```

## Code: WeekChart (barebones)

```
class WeekChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>WeekChart Chart</p>
    );
  }
}
```

## Thoughts:

Perhaps I need to do something inside `shouldComponentUpdate()` or one of the other lifecycle methods. I'm really not sure. The solution could be something trival for a seasoned ReactJS developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your child component to rerender when its data changes, inside the child component you should call setState from the componentWillReceiveProps() lifecycle method.

You child component should look like this;

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps !== this.props) {
        this.setState({yourState: nextProps.yourProperty});
    } else {
        do nothing
    }

}
```

This will prevent your component from re-rendering unless it receives new data. nextProps are the new properties coming into the component. If they are the same as the ones currently in the component, then do not setState and therefore do not re-render the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If neither child component has any internal state, just props, you should use the new `PureComponent` class to extend your child component class.  This will do a shallow check of the incoming props to determine whether your child component needs to update.  So:

`class WeekChart extends React.PureComponent {...}
class SocialChart extends React.PureComponent {...}`

You only need to use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` if you want more manual control of the rerender condition, in which case returning `false` *should* prevent the component from being updated (conditions apply).

You'd do this as follows:

`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.props.somePropYouCareAbout !== nextProps.somePropYouCareAbout;
}`

See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use PureComponent if you can do that since it was introduced for this exact reason.  Otherwise, there's no real reason to worry about this re-render.  Your component has nothing to change so even if the parent component re-renders the diff algorithm will see no changes and basically just skip over it.

I know it can be a perfectionist type of a thing so getting this to not re-render is ideal, but this would likely **not** be the culprit of a slow application.

Comment: The issue is that there is an animation when the chart renders, so the animation plays twice.

Comment: Can you give the specific code example that is giving problems?  Are you setting state at any point in the child components?